# How to track all the upstream issues my fork addressed

Tags: github, fork, issue-tracking, github-issues

My company wants to contribute on opensource projects and managers want an easy way to see which upstream issues were closed by forks from our organization.

Is there any way to maybe copy upstream issues to a fork or reference them in an easy way to track my organization contributions to a project?

Comment: Funny, we were discussing exactly this in the team meeting today.

Comment: Also looking at doing similar for many of my own forks. It's "not hard" to traverse with some reasonable simple Python API calls... but this *should* be literal point-and-click, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible through [GitHub Projects](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/trying-out-the-new-projects-experience/about-projects). Projects exist per the organization, not a particular repo. You can also link to issues and pull requests from repos of other organizations by entering `user/repo#issue` in the project's task description.

In the case of your scenario, suppose your team shares a GitHub organization. You can create project, then add items that reference your issues and pull requests, which exist within the open source project's repo. You can configure and organize your project's view(s) to display the information you want to show. Since this merely links to the issues/PRs from the open source repo, the original stays intact, and how they are displayed in your project stay in sync.